# How to access csv file from body in serverless (in python)

Tags: python, aws-lambda, readfile, endpoint, serverless

I have an endpoint and want to access the csv file.

Here is body when I print:
'body': '----------------------------533313155452638345592964\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.csv"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n\r\n0,0,Hello Darkness, my old friend\r\n----------------------------533313155452638345592964--\r\n', 'isBase64Encoded': False}

---

My function looks like this which gets data in event:
def data_file_prepare(event, context):

Comment: Can you share your endpoint?

Comment: Sorry, I can't. It's private

Comment: The file says, 'Hello Darkness, my old friend'. Clearly its a dummy data used for demo purpose. I can't help you unless I can replicate the issue on my system. You can always change your endpoint or even change the instance if security is your concern.

Comment: That's dummy text I've put in file to test firstly. You can just create endpoint in serverless and call it from postman with csv file in body and then get it in event.

Comment: Also you haven't even shared your code, just the function name! You should edit that to "My function name looks like this.." instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've got same error, but I used regrex for that.
You can reference following code snippet.

```
import re
 
data = '''
----------------------------533313155452638345592964\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.csv"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n\r\n0,0,Hello Darkness, my old friend\r\n----------------------------533313155452638345592964--\r\n
'''
 
r_csv = re.search(r'Content-Type: text/csv(.*\,\w)', data, re.DOTALL)
lst = [i for i in r_csv.group(1).split('\n') if i != '']
result = [i.split(',') for i in lst]
print(result)
```

I hope this will be helpful for you.